# rails - remotipart not working in Rails 3.2.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

Ever since updating to Rails 3.2.8 remotipart stopped working. I can see the iframe-transport.js and remotipart.js are being included in the page, and the form is submitted via AJAX, but the image is not included in the :params. When I disable Javascript image is getting included with :params, so this is very odd.

Can anyone think of something?

Answer (score -1):

May be the cause is incompatibility of current remotipart version with jquery 1.9 used in latest jquery-rails gem. It can be solved by manually applying [this patch](https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart/pull/57) (works for me).